# Confirm в ToDo App

Tags: javascript

Есть простое ToDo App. В том случае, если пользователь ввёл уже существующую в списке дел запись, интерфейс ToDo скрывается и появляется кастомный конфирм с возможностью выбора - добавить повторно или отказаться, все это осуществляется функцией toggleHiden, которая меняет класс "none" на "block" и наоборот. Проблема такая-как применить к кнопке "Да" функцию "createLi", которая создает дело, если пользователь соглашается добавить существующую запись и toggleHidden, чтобы снова вернуть интерфейс.

```js
let task = document.querySelector('.inputName').value;
const addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
const toDoList = document.querySelector('.toDoList');
const alertList = document.querySelector('.alert');
const formToDo = document.querySelector('.formToDo');
const yesBtn = document.getElementById('Yes');
const noBtn = document.getElementById('No');



function addToList() {
    task = document.querySelector('.inputName').value;
    if (task === '') {
        alert('Напишите что-нибудь!');
    } else {
        let alerts = true;
        let elementChildrens = toDoList.children;
        for (let i = 0, child; child = elementChildrens[i]; i++) {
            if (task === child.textContent) {
                alerts = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        function toggleHiden() {
            alertList.style.display = (alertList.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
            formToDo.style.display = (formToDo.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
            toDoList.style.display = (toDoList.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
        }

        function createLi() {
            let l1 = document.createElement('li');
            l1.setAttribute('tabindex', 2)
            l1.innerHTML = '<li></li>';
            l1.classList.add('toDo');
            l1.textContent = task;
            toDoList.appendChild(l1);
            document.querySelector('.inputName').value = '';
        }
        
        if (alerts) {
            createLi();

        } else {
            toggleHiden();
           
         yesBtn.addEventListener('click', createLi);
           
            noBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleHiden)
            
            document.querySelector('.inputName').value = '';

        }
    }
}

addBtn.addEventListener('click', addToList);
```

```css
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 1000px;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #f9f9f9 !important;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

.formToDo {
    margin: 100px;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    padding: 0 40px 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.heading {
    padding: 25px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.hiden {
    display: none;
}

.through {
    background: #888;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.toDo {
    padding: 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #eee;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.toDoList {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.inputName {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/* Установить все нечетные элементы списка в другой цвет (зебра) */
.toDo:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

/* Более темный фон-цвет при наведении */
.toDo:hover {
    background: #ddd;
}

.btn {
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.alert {
    margin-top: 250px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;

}

.close {
    padding-right: 10px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Список дел</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="formToDo">
        <h1 class="heading">Мой список дел:</h1>
        <input type="text" class="inputName form-control" placeholder="Напишите..." tabindex="1"/>
        <ol class="toDoList">
          <li class="toDo" tabindex="2">Сходить в магазин</li>    
          <li class="toDo" tabindex="2">Приготовить ужин</li>
        </ol>
        <button type="submit" id="addBtn" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="3">Добавить</button>
      </div>

      <div class="alert hiden">
        Такая запись уже есть. Всё равно добавить?
        <button id="Yes" class="btn btn-success">Да</button>
        <button id="No" class="btn btn-danger">Нет</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: я вроде отвечал уже...

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, да, и я благодарен Вам за тот ответ, но он не помог...

Comment: ну направление было; а где застопорилось?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov ну проблема в блоке else. Ну логика такая-если пользователь жмет "Да"-создается элемент, и надо вновь показывать основной интерфейс, то есть вызывать "toggleHiden" сразу же, не могу придумать, как и ее привязать к клику на "Да", ведь к нему уже "createLi" прикручена

Comment: `()=>{ toggle(); create() }`

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov не получается так, повторная запись просто не создается, confirm не показывается...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зарефакторил. Если есть вопросы, почему что-то как-то сделано -- пишите.

```js
const toDoList = document.querySelector('.toDoList')
const newCaptionInput = document.querySelector('.inputName')

function hasSameText() {
    return [...toDoList.children].some(child => newCaptionInput.value === child.textContent)
}

function showSameDialog(on) {
    document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = on ? 'block' : 'none' 
    document.querySelector('.formToDo').style.display = on ? 'none' : 'block'
}

function createLi() {
    const l1 = document.createElement('li')
    l1.setAttribute('tabindex', 2)
    l1.classList.add('toDo')
    l1.textContent = newCaptionInput.value
    toDoList.appendChild(l1)
    newCaptionInput.value = ''
}

function addToList() {
    task = document.querySelector('.inputName').value;
    if (task === '') alert('Напишите что-нибудь!');
    else if (!hasSameText()) createLi()
    else showSameDialog(true)
}

document.getElementById('Yes').addEventListener('click', ev => {
    showSameDialog(false)
    createLi()
})
document.getElementById('No').addEventListener('click', ev => {
    showSameDialog(false) 
})
document.getElementById('addBtn').addEventListener('click', ev => addToList())
```

```css
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 1000px;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #f9f9f9 !important;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

.formToDo {
    margin: 100px;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    padding: 0 40px 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.heading {
    padding: 25px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.hiden {
    display: none;
}

.through {
    background: #888;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.toDo {
    padding: 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #eee;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.toDoList {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.inputName {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/* Установить все нечетные элементы списка в другой цвет (зебра) */
.toDo:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

/* Более темный фон-цвет при наведении */
.toDo:hover {
    background: #ddd;
}

.btn {
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.alert {
    margin-top: 250px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;

}

.close {
    padding-right: 10px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Список дел</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="formToDo">
        <h1 class="heading">Мой список дел:</h1>
        <input type="text" class="inputName form-control" placeholder="Напишите..." tabindex="1"/>
        <ol class="toDoList">
            <li class="toDo" tabindex="2">Сходить в магазин</li>    
            <li class="toDo" tabindex="2">Приготовить ужин</li>
        </ol>
        <button type="submit" id="addBtn" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="3">Добавить</button>
        </div>

        <div class="alert hiden">
        Такая запись уже есть. Всё равно добавить?
        <button id="Yes" class="btn btn-success">Да</button>
        <button id="No" class="btn btn-danger">Нет</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Дальше мой вариант на React. Кода сильно меньше, и развивать проще.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Список дел</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<style>
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 1000px;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #f9f9f9 !important;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

.formToDo {
    margin: 100px;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    padding: 0 40px 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.heading {
    padding: 25px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.hiden {
    display: none;
}

.through {
    background: #888;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.toDo {
    padding: 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #eee;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.toDoList {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.inputName {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/* Установить все нечетные элементы списка в другой цвет (зебра) */
.toDo:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

/* Более темный фон-цвет при наведении */
.toDo:hover {
    background: #ddd;
}

.btn {
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.alert {
    margin-top: 250px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;

}

.close {
    padding-right: 10px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="calcContainer"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">

const { useState } = React

const initItems = () => [
    { caption: "Сходить в магазин", key: 1 },
    { caption: "Приготовить ужин", key: 2 },
]

const useTodoList = () => {
    const [ newCaption, setNewCaption ] = useState("")
    const [ items, setItems ] = useState(initItems)
    const addItem = newCaption.length <= 0 ? null : () => {
        setItems(cItems=>[...cItems,{ caption: newCaption, key: Date.now() }])
        setNewCaption("")
    }
    const sameCaptionFound = items.some(item => item.caption === newCaption)
    return { items, addItem, newCaption, setNewCaption, sameCaptionFound }
}

const App = () =>{
    const { items, addItem, newCaption, setNewCaption, sameCaptionFound } = useTodoList()
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="formToDo">
            <h1 className="heading">Мой список дел:</h1>
            <input type="text" className="inputName form-control" placeholder="Напишите..." tabIndex="1" value={newCaption} onChange={ev => setNewCaption(ev.target.value)} />
            <ol className="toDoList">
              {items.map(item=>(
                <li className="toDo" tabIndex="2" key={item.key}>{item.caption}</li>
              ))}
            </ol>
            {!addItem && <span>Введите что-то</span>}
            {sameCaptionFound && <span>Такая запись уже есть</span>}
            <button type="submit" id="addBtn" className="btn btn-primary" tabIndex="3" onClick={ev=>addItem()} disabled={addItem?undefined:true}>Добавить</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('.calcContainer'))

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо за рефакторинг, решение проблемы и вариант на react! Это задание учебное, им пока запрещено пользоваться, но как только дойдем до него, обязательно воспульзуюсь Вашим примером! Ещё раз благодарю!

Comment: Всегда рад. Ответ можно принимать галочкой

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
const buttonYes = document.querySelector('.btn-success')
//через делегирование на документ
document.addEventListener('click', e =>{
  if(e.target === buttonYes){
    createLi()
  }
})
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]